# Django Endless Pagination - Multiple paginations in the same page

Tags: python, django, django-endless-pagination

My Django version is 1.10.5

With Django Endless Pagination 3.0.1 i want to show two or more paginated lists(see code) on my site.

For that i try to do this [tutorial](http://django-el-pagination.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.1/multiple_pagination.html) but the solution raises everytime an error if i use a second  variable or multiple variables. The second variable(the querystring) in the tutorial is `"other_entries_page"`.

The answer from the testserver:  **Invalid arguments for u'paginate' tag**

I have no idea whats going wrong.

Here is the code from the tutorial:

```
{% load el_pagination_tags %}

{% paginate entries %}
{% for entry in entries %}
{# your code to show the entry #}
{% endfor %}
{% show_pages %}

{# "other_entries_page" is the new querystring key #}
{% paginate other_entries using "other_entries_page" %}
{% for entry in other_entries %}
{# your code to show the entry #}
{% endfor %}
{% show_pages %}
```

The variables that i mean are GET-variables(like: http://example.com/?**page=2**).

I hope you can help me.

Comment: what is in "entries" and "other_entries"? paginate does not like whatever it is in it.

Comment: oh sry my bad, for example lets say  the "entries" is from blog A and the "other_entries" is from blog B . The content is not important.

Comment: can u provide traceback? May be entries / other_entries is None or not a list?

Comment: The two lists exist and they are not empty.


The problem is:
**Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError**
**Exception Value: Invalid arguments for u'paginate' tag**


Here is the error:
**{% paginate other_entries using "other_entries_page" %}**

Comment: the default tag "?page=" works fine but when i  use other tags/querystrings like "?other_entries_page=" the system call an error why?

The idea is to have two parameters to retrieve the right page for each pagination.
**http://example.com?page=2&other_entries_page=3**
Pagination 1 is on page 2 and Pagination 2 is on page 3 (on the same page)